# RecyclerView click listener, why this simpler approach is not used more often

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, kotlin

New to Android development here. I am creating a `RecyclerView` that presents a new activity when certain items are clicked. I searched online and all of them would define a click listener interface, pass the listener to view holders, and ultimately call `startActivity` from the main activity.

Alternatively, I came up with the following. Since nobody is using this approach, what's wrong with it? It is just a few lines of code in the adapter class and seems to work equally well

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is certainViewHolder -> {
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, DetailedActivity::class.java)
                    holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
            else -> ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with second approach? Why nobody is using it

Comment: Looks like this is more like a hypothetical question :) Is it actually "not working"? It looks fine, I don't see any issue with it. It can also be improved, I think. Since you are not binding any data with your views and not passing anything to the activity, there is no need to create a listener every time in onBindViewHolder. In this case you can do it only once in onCreateViewHolder while inflating the layout. Although this is a very subtle improvement and will not make a big difference. Your approach looks totally fine.

Comment: I believe that's because starting an activity inside the adapter isn't very "pretty". People like to keep activity stuff within the activity.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin it does work, just want to know the reason people don't use this simpler approach more often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your approach and many people use it. Usually first approach used most of time because calling method using interface is good practice. When we create a project using certain architecture like MVP or MVVM or any other we need to call all method using interface. Currently in your project you just need to start a activity but many times we to perform longer and difficult task so it better to perform in relate activity. Through we can collect all method in same place.